# Is there a Regex to not match words containing only A-Z, 0-9, "/", "-" and "." in textstrings?

Tags: regex

Trying to not match words that have 5 or more chars and containing only A-Z, 0-9, "/", "-" and "." in the textstrings.

Tried a million different Regexes. The one I use now is:

(?<=[A-Z0-9/.-]{5,}\s).*

This actually works rather ok, but I miss the text in front of the expression, when the expression is in a middle of a line.

List:

```
Test ABC123 Test
ABC123 Test
Test ABC123
Test ABC-123 Test
ABC-123 Test
Test ABC-123
Test ABC/123 Test
ABC/123 Test
Test ABC/123
```

Expected result:

```
Test ABC123 Test
Test
Test ABC123
Test ABC-123 Test
Test
Test ABC-123
Test ABC/123 Test
Test
Test ABC/123
```

Basically I just want the expression removed if it in the beginning of the string.

Comment: How about `^\S{5,} ?`?

Comment: You say you are using a variable-length lookbehind assertion?

Comment: From the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: You get those results because you are using a positive lookbehind `(?<=`  which is non consuming and asserts what is on the left is `[A-Z0-9/.-]{5,}\s` If that assertion is true, then match 0 or more times any char  except a newline. Note that `\s` also matches a newline. See https://regex101.com/r/DrGsvE/1 You can omit the lookbehind and use an anchor `^` instead https://regex101.com/r/GakPrH/1

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
(?<=^[A-Z0-9/.-]{5,}\s).*
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.  It would be helpful if you would specify the language you are using.  This is Java.  It simply removes the pattern if it exists at the beginning of the String.

```
String[] test = {
    "Test ABC123 Test", "ABC123 Test", "Test ABC123",
    "Test ABC-123 Test", "ABC-123 Test", "Test ABC-123",
    "Test ABC/123 Test", "ABC/123 Test", "Test ABC/123"
};

for (String t : test) {
    String nt = t.replaceAll("^[A-Z0-9/.-]{5,}\\s(.*)", "$1");
    System.out.println("Before: " + t);
    System.out.println("After:  " + nt);
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
}
```

Comment: I am not saying that the string is *likely* to have newline characters, but `(.*)` would not match the rest of the line if any were present unless you used the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag.

Comment: Actually, the way I used the pattern it does match because it just finds one or more instances of the match.  So the newline is not relevant.  You would be correct if I was matching the complete string.

Comment: Actually, if there were no newline characters I think you would be matching the entire string and replacing it with everything that is not `[A-Z0-9/.-]{5,}\s`. But if there is a newline, then you would be matching everything up to to but not including that newline, so it ends up working anyway. To see what I am talking about, replace `"$1"` with `""` and see what you end up with.

Answer (score 0):

This looks for the regular expression `^[A-Z0-9/.-]{5,}\s+` and if found replaces it with the empty string.

A Python implementation:

```
import re

strings = [
    "Test ABC123 Test",
    "ABC123 Test",
    "Test ABC123",
    "Test ABC-123 Test",
    "ABC-123 Test",
    "Test ABC-123",
    "Test ABC/123 Test",
    "ABC/123 Test",
    "Test ABC/123"
]

regex = re.compile(r'^[A-Z0-9/.-]{5,}\s+')

for string in strings:
    print(string, "->", regex.sub("", string))
```

Prints:

```
Test ABC123 Test -> Test ABC123 Test
ABC123 Test -> Test
Test ABC123 -> Test ABC123
Test ABC-123 Test -> Test ABC-123 Test
ABC-123 Test -> Test
Test ABC-123 -> Test ABC-123
Test ABC/123 Test -> Test ABC/123 Test
ABC/123 Test -> Test
Test ABC/123 -> Test ABC/123
```